# Server IP Address - Returns Hexadecimal number

Tags: c#, ip-address

i have this function to get the server ip address:

```
public static string GetIpAddressServer()
{
    String ip = "";
    try
    {
        string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        HostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        ip = ipAddress.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ip = "";
    }
    return ip;
}
```

But it returns something like

```
fe80::3c7f:4fc4:884d:b7f5%11
```

What's wrong?

Comment: That is an ipv6 address. They look like that

Comment: And people still wonder why IPv6 is not becoming the standard...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the IPv4 version you can do that:

```
 var address = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostname)
.AddressList
.First(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

[.Net IPAddress IPv4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048132/net-ipaddress-ipv4)